# Identify a movie about people melting in a room

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember watching this movie in around 2005 or older. It's in English and subbed to my country's language. It's in color. It genre is probably Horror and SciFi. I vaguely remember the plot but I'll try my best.

There are a group of people who have come to a girl's house. The girl is a best friend from someone in the group. The girl welcomes the group and serves them food and drinks. After sometime something happened in the living room where the group was eating. Their bodies start to literally melt. I think it has something to do with the ground / floor because I remember one of the group is not melting because he stepped out of the room.

Comment: Long shot, but could it be Society? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0098354/ - that's kinda melty.

Comment: Vahn, any input on whether it's _Society_? Or does the search continues? :)

Comment: No, it's not Society